# How to get beaver builder custom module settings data in same file where module settings created?

Tags: wordpress

In beaver builder custom module development how to get created settings results in same page where I am creating those settings. For example if I am creating settings in `custom.php` file and those are available in `frontend.php` file, while I want to get those saved values in `custom.php` file ... is it possible ? How to do that if this is possible ?

Here is my data in custom.php file:

```
FLBuilder::register_module('FLExampleModuleGallery', array(
'general'       => array( // Tab
    'title'         => __('General', 'fl-builder'), // Tab title
    'sections'      => array( // Tab Sections
        'general'       => array( // Section
            'title'         => __('Section Title', 'fl-builder'), // Section Title
            'fields'        => array( // Section Fields
                'select_field'   => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Show Filter or Not?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'no_of_posts' => array(
                    'type'          => 'my-custom-field',
                    'label'         => __('Provide your desired number of Posts', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => '8'
                ),
                'no_of_cols' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Provide your desired number of Cols', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-2',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('2', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('3', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-3'      => __('4', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-4'      => __('6', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_overlay' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to Show Overlay?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_lightbox' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to Open Image in lightbox?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_lightbox_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Link Icon in Lightbox?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_title' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Title?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_title_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to use Link in Post Title?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_content' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Content?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
                'show_link' => array(
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'label'         => __('Do You Want to show Post Link?', 'fl-builder'),
                    'default'       => 'option-1',
                    'options'       => array(
                        'option-1'      => __('Yes', 'fl-builder'),
                        'option-2'      => __('No', 'fl-builder')
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    )
),

  ));
```

Now here is the code in `frontend.php` to get those values:

```
$show_lightbox = $settings->show_lightbox;
$show_lightbox_link = $settings->show_lightbox_link;
$show_title = $settings->show_title;
$show_title_link = $settings->show_title_link;
$show_content = $settings->show_content;
$show_link = $settings->show_link;
```

How to get these above values in the `custom.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom method in your own module class just like this:

```
public function  custom_file(){
  $settings = $this->settings;
  require_once 'includes/custom.php';
}
```

now call that method to the enqueue_scripts() like this:

```
public function enqueue_scripts(){
  $this->custom_file();
}
```

or in your frontend.php:

```
$module->custom_file();
```

finally create custom.php then check $settings value to see if it's working

```
var_dump($settings);
```

hopefully this would be acceptable by modern development standards

Comment: then who cares if your name is goto? are you the owner of stackoverflow? sorry but I'm just confused, you just came out of nowhere then suddenly you order me where to post, what to post. can you tell me who gives you the privileged to do that?

Comment: When you contribute to stack overflow by posting good answer or goods responses, you earn reputation (the number close to your name). The reputation give you privileges (the list is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). Stack overflow works mostly by the help of people like you and me. So yes, I can decide to edit your post to make it clearer, and some other people in the community approved my edit. You don't have to take it personnaly, it's to help you posting goods questions/answers on the website. If you still have some question do not hesitate to ask them!

Comment: Stack overflow is not a forum or another website. You don't really own your questions: The goal of the website is to make good question to help future readers. In order to help improving the site, anyone of the community can edit to improve anyone answer, as far as it is accepted by the community

Comment: ok thank you for explaining very well, and I apologize for my rudeness, I just don't understand what's going on. as you can see my reputation is only 1

Comment: No problem :] we all started like you ;)